# Changing ID from nth to last row if something happens at nth row

Tags: stata

My data has some problem. The survey is conducted on housing unit. So the two rows with the same person ID might not actually indicate the same person.

I want to assign different ID for actually different person.

Let's say I have this data.

```
id  yearmonth  age 
1   200001      12
1   200002      12
1   200003      14
1   200004      14
1   200005      14
```

3rd row is definitely different person. Its age increase by 2.

So I want to change ID like

```
id  yearmonth  age 
1   200001      12
1   200002      12
10   200003      14
10   200004      14
10   200005      14
```

How can I do this? I think I can change the ID of 3rd row by writing

```
bysort id (yearmonth): replace id=id*10 if age[_n-1]>age+1 | age[_n-1]+1<age

(where I multiply by 10 because all IDs have the same number of numbers, so that multiplying by 10 won't give any duplicate)
```

But how can I change all subsequent rows?

Answer (score 1):

Building on what you have, something like this might do what you want.

```
bysort id (yearmonth): generate idchange = age[_n-1]>age+1 | age[_n-1]+1<age
bysort id (yearmonth): generate numchange = sum(idchange)
replace id = 10*id + (idchange-1) if idchange>0
```

Note that this will handle the case where one original id has two or more changes detected. For up to 10 changes, anyhow.

```
id  yearmonth  age 
2   200001      12
2   200002      14
2   200003      15
2   200004      18
2   200005      18
```

Comment: Thank you. But numchange was created and then not used at all. Perhaps the two occurrences of idchange in 3rd row should be replaced by numchange?